# Can I switch to Gnome 3 without problems without having to wait for 17.10? If so, how can I switch to gnome 3?

Tags: gnome

Can I switch to Gnome 3 without problems or it's better just waiting for 17.10?

If I can do the switch without problems, how can I switch to gnome 3?

Is this how I can do it?

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-default-settings
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-settings
sudo apt-get install gnome-documents gnome-boxes
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar*
```

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Install Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: @MarkYisri I already have the default Ubuntu distributed by Canonical.

Comment: That isn't Gnome. It's Unity. Okay, technically Unity uses Gnome, but not the shell you're looking for. In general, avoid installing two desktop environments. You might get away with it here because they share stuff. Just run the first command.

Answer (score 1):

The only command you need:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop && gnome-shell
```

During the installation you will be asked to choose between `gdm` and `lightdm` so you don't need another command to switch.